# Probabilistic distribution of sandpile model type

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, sandpile

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph. Assume that $m\leqslant |V|$ hedgehogs sit in the vertices of $G$. If there are $r\geqslant 2$ hedgehogs in the same vertex $v\in V$, one of them goes to a randomly (say, uniformly, but other models are also possible) chosen neighbor of $v$. Repeat this until no two hedgehogs occupy the same vertex of $G$. With probability 1 this stops after finite number of migrations (easy to see). Distribution does not depend on how we choose an overpopulated vertex on each step (indeed, if $v$ is overpopulated, we must resettle it sometimes, so we may choose direction of migration from $v$ preliminary, as migrations commute). So, given initial distribution of hedgehogs, we get a random admissible ('overpopulated-free') hedgehogs distribution.

My question is how is it called and where was it studied if it was.

Comment: The model is Manna model (see Two-state model of self-organized criticality, Manna), but without boundary. I did not find even studies of Manna model on arbitrary graphs, so it is very possible that no term is coined for the distribution you described.